# Is it possible to read and write to a .h file with objective c?

Tags: objective-c, file, plugins

I'm trying to make an xcode plugin that needs to write something to the .h file from the .m file. I haven't been able to find a stackoverflow post with an answer on how to do this. I've tried this code

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I've also tried using the `StringWithContentsOfFile` method, however they both return nil. Is it because you can't read an .h file with this code or is it something else I'm missing.

filePath is this and it's a correct filepath, my ftp client can read it atleast file:///Users/myUserName/Documents/code/macOsDev/XcodePlugIns/XcoderPlugin/XcoderPlugin/XcoderPlugin.h

So my question is, how do I read and write to a .h file? Thanks in advance.

EDIT as requested, some more code however this is as far as I've gotten to the read/write part of my plugin.

```
NSString *filePath = path;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSString *contents1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

contents is @"" because data is nil 
and contents1 is just nil;
error is error

```
NSError * domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 260
```

in the debugger, but I'm not sure I'm using this error thing correctly.

Comment: `+ (instancetype)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` should do that, no reason for not reading an .h file. Post more of your code. Note also you should declare that variable as NSMutableString if you want to change its content.

Comment: You can write/read from a .h file. Is the .h file read/write protected?

Comment: Do you need to read the `.h` file from `.app` or from the hard disk?

Comment: is the path prefixed by "file://" ?

Comment: I used @ShantiK 's answer and can now read the file, I just need to write to it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "/Users/myUserName/Documents/code/macOsDev/XcodePlugIns/XcoderPlugin/XcoderPlugin/XcoderPlugin.h".
Dont use 'file://' prefix

Following is the code for reading and writing

```
NSString *path = @"your/path/tp/.h/file";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
//Get the contents of the file into the mutable string
NSMutableString *contents = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//Make changes to your mutable string
[contents appendString:@"abc"];
//Write it back to the file
[contents writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Removing the file:// prefix seems to fix the issue with reading the file, I now get the contents of the file. Now I just need to know how to write to the file if you can help me with that?

Comment: Please ask a new question regarding writing the file and if the answer here helped, please check it as such.

Comment: @Volker Well my question was how do i read and write, and I've only gotten an answer to how I could read the file, so it only answers half my question. I gave him and upvote because it was helpful but it still only answers half my question.

Comment: @Hafax.. Take the contents of the .h file into a NSMutableString. Make whatever changes you want in the string and then use 'writeToFile: atomically: encoding: error:' method to write the changes back to the .h file